# Palindrome with stacks

Tags: python

So I'm trying to check if a word is a palindrome using stacks.  I've gotten it work with one exception.  If I try the word 'level' it works, however, if I try 'levell' it comes back true.  Here's my code:

```
import Stack

def check_palindrome():
    s = Stack.Stack()
    word = input('Enter a word: ')
    for x in word:
        s.push(x)

    palindrome = True
    for x in range(len(word)):
        if s.pop() == word[x]:
            palindrome = True
        else:
            palindrome = False

    if palindrome == True:
        print(word, 'is a palindrome.')
    else:
        print(word, 'is not a palindrome.')         


check_palindrome()
```

I can't seem to figure out why it is saying it's true.  Maybe I'm thinking about this incorrectly.  My train of thought was to add each letter to the stack using

```
for x in word:
    s.push(x)
```

Then to pop it because of FILO and compare the last to the first.  Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: because you don't break when you find a letter not matching, you only really look at the last letter. Your algorithm ultimately only care if the first and last letters are the same. Try with for example `example` to see that. What lacks in your code is that, when a word is not a palindrome, it can never be a palindrome again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, there are much better ways to check that a word is a palindrome, using reversed string and comparing to itself for instance (there are a ton of answers on this site solving this).

That said, about your problem:

```
for x in range(len(word)):
    if s.pop() == word[x]:
        palindrome = True
    else:
        palindrome = False
```

If one letter doesn't match, it should `break` the loop, or else the answer is conditioned only by the last loop iteration. I'd write:

```
for letter in word:
    if s.pop() != letter:
        palindrome = False
        break      # one mismatch: bail out
else:
    palindrome = True # OK
```

(`else` of the `for` loop is executed only if all iterations were achieved without encountering `break`)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you intentionally want to use Stack, why not check if the word is equal to its reverse, like so?

```
def check_palindrome(word):
    palindrome = word == word[::-1]  # True if word is equal to its reverse

    if palindrome == True:
        print(word, 'is a palindrome.')
    else:
        print(word, 'is not a palindrome.')
```

Comment: It's intentional, I know it would be a lot simpler without but it's a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your comparison continues even after you find a mismatch, so `palindrome` can get reset to `True` even after it gets set to `False`. So overall, you're actually only checking if the first and last letter of your word is the same. You can fix this by `break`ing out of the loop when you find a mismatch.

Also just as a style note, you can replace `if palindrome == True:` with `if palindrome:`